# standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory" while copying shell script to the container

Tags: docker

I am trying to build docker image. One of the simple requirement is that I have to copy a shell script from my host to docker container. So I use following Dockerfile:

```
ADD script.sh /usr/local/bin/script.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/script.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/script.sh"]
```

I apply docker-compose build, which results in success but when I apply docker-compose up, it leads to an error -> standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"

Any guesses, going nuts with it and for very simple requirement.

Answer (score 0):

That was terribly painful, the **Dockerfile** execution from ***docker-compose up*** command started to work just when I replaced **#!/bin/bash** with **#!/bin/sh** in **script.sh** I mentioned in my problem statement.

I hope this helps someone who is struggling with the similar pattern involving script files present in their problem solution design.